# How do you get a label to be read as a number?

Tags: ios, swift

My map annotation works well when physically putting the numbers in, but, how do I use it so,

**for example**, `latitudelabel.text` is read as the latitude rather than *38.897957*? 
Here is the code:

```
func showEmergenyOnMap() {

    let emergency = MKPointAnnotation()
    emergency.title = "Ongoing Emergency"
    emergency.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.897957, longitude: -77.036560)
    Map.addAnnotation(emergency)

}
```

Comment: you have to cast your `String` value in `Double` before putting in `CLLocationCoordinate2D`

Comment: If you're trying conversion between `Double` & `String`, then it's a duplicate question. It's unclear from your question, which way you want the conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Covert string to double.

```
let lati = Double(label.text)
// do same for longi
```

Then init coordinate

```
let coords = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lati, longitude: longi)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, I just had to add an exclamation point to the ending of label.text and lati (in coords). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`UILabel`'s `text` property is an `Optional` variable so it can have a `value` or a `nil`. First of all you need to safely `unwrap` that `value` because `CLLocationDegrees` initializer takes a non-optional `String`. You can see the below example on how to convert labels text to `CLLocationCoordinate2D`,

```
var latitude: CLLocationDegrees = 0.0
var longitude: CLLocationDegrees = 0.0

if let latText = latitudelabel.text, let lat = CLLocationDegrees(latText) {
    latitude = lat
}

if let longText = longitudelabel.text, let long = CLLocationDegrees(longText) {
    longitude = long
}

let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
```